# Mongoosastic geospatial schema mapper

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoosastic

My schema looks something like this for `mongoose`:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
    id:          ObjectId,
    geo:         { 
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
            default: 'Point'
        },
        coordinates: [{
            type: Number,
            es_lat_lon: true,
            es_type: 'geo_point'
        }]
    }
});
```

Then I add `mongoosastic` plugin to `mongoose` initiate the model and create the mappings for `mongoosastic`

```
var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: config.es_url,
    requestTimeout: Infinity,
    keepAlive: true
});
LocationSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, { esClient: esClient })

var Location = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);

/**
 * mongoosastic create mappings
 */
Location.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('mapping created!');
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});
```

Now I get this error `[Error: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [{default=Point, enum=[Point, LineString, Polygon], required=true, type=string}] declared on field [geo]]]`

The full error in the log:

```
{ 
    [Error: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [{default=Point, enum=[Point, LineString, Polygon], required=true, type=string}] declared on field [geo]]]
    status: '400',
    displayName: 'BadRequest',
    message: 'MapperParsingException[No handler for type [{default=Point, enum=[Point, LineString, Polygon], required=true, type=string}] declared on field [geo]]'
}
```

My question is am I doing this completely wrong or am I just missing something small? The way I am doing this works for `mongoose`, only `mongoosastic` is having trouble and I understand why, but I can't be the first to run into this (reason why `mongoosastic` is having trouble is it sees `type` and does not expect it to have a type - at least that is what I think it is having trouble with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
coordinates: [{
        type: Number,
        es_lat_lon: true,
        es_type: 'geo_point'
    }]
```

Try

```
coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        es_type: 'geo_point'
    }
```

**EDIT**:

OP Posted this solution.
Changed:

```
geo: { 
    type: { 
        type: String, ...... 
    }, 
    coordinates: [
       { type: Number,      ..... }
    ] 
}
```

To

```
geo: { 
    point_type: { 
        type: String, ...... 
    }, 
    coordinates: [
        { type: Number, ..... }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: looking at this again after so long I think I know what it is now. I don't think `mongoosastic` likes `geo: { type: { type: String, ...... }, coordinates: [{ type: Number, ..... }] }` I think it is the type and that having a type.

Comment: that was it, if I changed `geo: { type: { type: String, ...... }, coordinates: [{ type: Number, ..... }] }` to `geo: { point_type: { type: String, ...... }, coordinates: [{ type: Number, ..... }] }` it has no problem

Comment: since you helped you can add that to your answer as an edit/update and I will accept it as the answer